# Azure Functions error: The connection string for the monitored collection is in an invalid format

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I created a Azure function that is triggered by Cosmos DB on local.
And my `function.json` looks like below.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "documents",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "DB_URI",
      "databaseName": "test",
      "collectionName": "messages",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
...
```

And I tried to run this function locally, then I got this error.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create Collection Information for messages in database test with lease leases in database test : The connection string for the monitored collection is in an invalid format, please use AccountEndpoint=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXX;.

This error says I should use this format `AccountEndpoint=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXX;` as my connection string but my value looks like this currently.

`local.settings.json`

```
"DB_URI": "mongodb://...",
```

How and where can I get the valid value which I should put here?
On Connection String page, I cannot find the value which uses the format above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to connect to Mongo API account, I can see the url is starting with Mongo API,

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#supported-apis),

> Azure Cosmos DB bindings are only supported for use with the SQL API.
> For all other Azure Cosmos DB APIs, you should access the database
> from your function by using the static client for your API, including
> MongoDB API, Cassandra API, Gremlin API, and Table API.

Comment: Ah I see. I was missing this..Thanks for telling me!